# Neural network in keras and tensorflow for multiplying features

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

The idea of this model is that it learns, through neural networks, to perform the multiplication of two feactures, so I created a training dataset with multiplications of random numbers from 0 to 100. As the idea is that it learns to multiply in any situation, I created training data a) with random numbers up to 100 and b) with random numbers from 1000 to 5000.

I created the neural network below for this, however it does not fit well with the test data “b”.

```
    model = tf.keras.Sequenenter code heretial()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2,input_dim = 2))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 64,activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 32,activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
```

Compared to the "a" test data, the prediction makes sense. But comparing with the test data "b", it presents a similar curve, but with very distant values.

[Data test x Data predict "a"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkjBh.png)

[Data test x Data predict "b"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0obCC.png)

[Data predict "b"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV98E.png)

If you want to see my complete code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rdAhZnHlxyXHHDF2D_grog05oDwYbXHa?usp=sharing

Could you help me with my model to generalize well to data much larger than training data?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, are you normalizing your data?

Comment: Yes, i tried it with MinMaxScaler () and RobustScaler (). Any other suggestions for normalization?
thanks

Comment: You generally cannot assume a neural network to "work correctly" outside the range of the training data. If you need to multiply features, I would suggest that you do this by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Using the scaling provided by you in the comments of your notebook results in a different scaling for training and test data. For example if there is a 100 value in your training data its normalized value should be the same in your test data, which is not the case right now. The easiest way to normalize the data in your case is simply doing it from the beginning, e.g. here

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=a, columns=['a'])
df['b']= b
df['mult'] = df['a']*df['b']
# Scale your data here
```

In any case, I am not sure if this would solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I applied the normalization in the indicated place and the results became more accurate, but the same behavior remains for the training data "b".
thanks

Comment: Note that the same scaling you use for training must be used when testing your network. If you provide a range [0,100] for training and a set [0,50] for testing, both must use the same scaling factor. Note you also need to scale the labels. Finally, if you train your network in [0,100] you should not expect that it will work correctly if you provide it with a range of [100, 200]. I think this is what xdurch0 means.